# Finding strings which contain a given substring

Tags: list-manipulation

Using the following commands (which may be inefficient) I can generate all words of length $j$ on the alphabet $\{0,1\}$:

`sd[st_]:=StringDelete[st, " "]`

`name[j_]:=Map[sd,Map[StringRiffle,Tuples[{0, 1}, j] ]]`

Suppose I want to find all words on length 6 which contain as a substring `101`, how do I do this? I have tried using `StringCases` but this seems to only give me strings that start or end with `101`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two additional methods (both faster than `Select[strings, StringContainsQ["101"]]`):

```
strings = Map[StringJoin, Tuples[{"0", "1"}, 6]];

Pick[strings, StringContainsQ["101"] @ strings]
```

> ```
> {"000101", "001010", "001011", "001101", "010100", "010101", 
> "010110", "010111", "011010", "011011", "011101", "100101", "101000", 
> "101001", "101010", "101011", "101100", "101101", "101110", "101111", 
> "110100", "110101", "110110", "110111", "111010", "111011", "111101"}
> ```

A slower alternative:

```
Pick[strings, StringMatchQ["*101*"]@strings]
```

> same result

Answer (score 5):

Two different methods:

```
strings = Map[StringJoin, Tuples[{"0", "1"}, 6]];
Flatten @ StringCases[
  strings,
  StartOfString ~~ ___ ~~ "101" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfString
]
Select[strings, StringContainsQ["101"]]
```

The `Select` variant is slightly faster for large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = Map[StringJoin, Tuples[{"0", "1"}, 6]];
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[Characters[s], x : {___, "1", "0", "1", ___} :> StringJoin[x]]
```

{"000101", "001010", "001011", "001101", "010100", "010101",
"010110", "010111", "011010", "011011", "011101", "100101", "101000",
"101001", "101010", "101011", "101100", "101101", "101110", "101111",
"110100", "110101", "110110", "110111", "111010", "111011", "111101"}

Answer (score 2):

```
s = Map[StringJoin, Tuples[{"0", "1"}, 6]];
```

---

Using `StringFreeQ` and `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[s, x_ /; StringFreeQ[x, "101"]]
```

*Result*:

> {"000101", "001010", "001011", "001101", "010100", "010101", "010110", "010111", "011010",
> "011011", "011101", "100101", "101000", "101001", "101010", "101011", "101100", "101101",
> "101110", "101111", "110100", "110101", "110110", "110111", "111010", "111011", "111101"}